# How do I fetch the Transaction ID from PayPal website to my web site?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using Paypal sandbox testing module in my Shopping cart site. I have test account in paypal sandbox. i am sending amount to paypal. After payment success when retun back to my web page I want to get transaction id and amount.Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use Paypal IPN.  You can get the Paypal transaction id, amount, and a slew of other information, using Paypal IPN.  Basically, this is where Paypal will do an https post back to your site after a transaction, and send all of the info for the transaction.  See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/ for info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify redirect url.You can have two urls one for success and other for failure.Thats how i implemented it in one of my project (Dont have it now with me for reference).

Take a look [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article928-online-payments-using-paypal-integration-with-aspnet-.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474197/PayPal-Gateway-Integration-in-ASP-NET).This [link](http://www.spiderweblogic.com/Paypal-Integration-Code.aspx) has an sample project.It may help.